# Unity WebGL crashing on loadscene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, unity-webgl

Just finished a small game project and have uploaded the complete project via WebGL, however currently the game loads the first scene and crashes trying to load the main scene, there are no errors in the compiler and it works perfectly in the editor.

I'm not sure if this is just for me, so could someone try the game, it freezes(audio still playing) when you click play in the main menu.
http://www.willcardoso.co.uk/UnityGameBuilds/Mario/Completed/index.html

I believe that maybe it could be because the file size may be too big for google? Maximum Used Total Memory = 190mb. If this is the issue, any help on slimming down the file?

Comment: check thoroughly what scripts are being executed when you hit play. It seems like something goes into an infinite loop on the main thread.

Comment: Well try debugging in webgl: put Debug.Logs in every step of your code until you can pinpoint the exact location of the crash

Comment: Would this still be the case even though it works fine without errors in the editor?

Comment: No, you are not the only one, there is actually quite a number of people having this issue, searching forums. Did you figure out what the problem was?